# Console will keep closing out instead of reading the string within the if statements

Tags: c++

What I want to do is to have the player "select" what class they want to be, and each class has a number. A different number will print out a different string into the console, and I wanted to do that through making if statements. In other words, the player will type in a choice and their choice will end up printing something from a different if statement. However, every time I run the code, the program will just end when it asks the user what class they want to use, and won't print out the message that is for that class.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;


int main()
{
    int Name,Class;
    cout << "Welcome to the world of Jumanji!\n\n";
    cout << "Please Tell me your name:";
    cin >> Name;
    cout << "\n\nOkay, so your name is " << Name << "? Welcome to the world of Jumanji - A game for those who seek to find a way to leave their world behind\n\n";
    cout << "I am a fellow adventurer who will aid you during your journey\n\n";
    cout << "Alright " << Name << "I need you to tell me what you will be playing as\n\n";
    cout << "1.Archaeologist\n2.Cartographer\n3.Commando\n4.Pilot\n5.Zoologist ";
    cin >> Class;

    if (Class == 1) {
        cout << "Are you sure that you want to be a Archaeologist?";
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (Class == 2) {
        cout << "Are you sure that you want to be a Cartographer?";
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (Class == 3) {
        cout << "Are you sure that you want to be a Commando?";
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (Class == 4) {
        cout << "Are you sure that you want to be a Pilot?";
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (Class == 5) {
        cout << "Are you sure that you want to be a Zoologist?";
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your name an integer? I don't think so.

Comment: Do you have a debugger available? You should set a breakpoint on the first `if` statement and see what the value of `Class` is. Let me know what operating system and development environment you are using and I or someone can suggest a debugger to use.

Answer (score 1):

so, name should be `string`, not `int`.

```
string Name;
int Class;
```

Because the user might enter "John Doe" as the name, `cin >> Name;` would only get the "John", and leave "Doe", in the buffer which now ends up in `Class`, that causes `Class` to contain an arbitrary value. Thus the `if else` doesn't work. using `getline()` should fix things.

```
string Name;
int Class;
cout << "Welcome to the world of Jumanji!\n\n";
cout << "Please Tell me your name:";
getline(cin, Name);
```

Comment: That would solve the behavior, but can you also explain why the code inside the `if() else if()` cascade isn't executed?

Comment: see my answer again.

Comment: Thank you. Doing this fixed every issue I had. I should have paid more attention to what I was doing. Really do appreciate it.